# Facebook SDK upgrade and android.support v7:25

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, dependencies

So I recently tried running my app which had been working fine until facebook updated their sdk which caused problems with different variations of android.support v7:25.

The dependency that caused the issue was 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+'.  To fix the issue i just specified a version that I wanted.

My question is, will this cause my apps that have already been published with the 4+ dependency to crash and should I immediately update my app with the specific version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should always define any dependencies with specific version ( As per experience I do have).

You should not define dependencies like this with any of i.e. with Facebook or Google etc.

If you use dependencies like defining `4+`, then it upgrades automatically when required.